# How to update a field with a UUID if it doesn't have one already?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator

I have a text field called `GIS_ID` which I would like to populate with a unique [**UUID**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) only if it doesn't have a valid UUID already. That is, if the field is NULL, or contains any other value other than a valid UUID, then I want it to populate it with a UUID.  If there is already a valid UUID in the field, then I want it to do nothing.

I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.4.1 Standard License and I want to populate the field using the field calculator.  I'm also aware of **[GUID Fields](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/arcgis-field-data-types.htm#GUID-97064FAE-B42E-4DC3-A5C9-9A6F12D053A8)** in ArcGIS but they aren't suitable for the client's purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this with the following codeblock for the field calculator with the Python parser.  I used the [**uuid**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html) module as well as the [**re**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module.

The regular expression for UUIDs is:

*[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{12}*

```
def CalcUUID(n):
  import uuid
  import re
  rePattern=re.compile('[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{12}')
  if n==None:
    return str(uuid.uuid4()).upper()
  elif rePattern.match(n):
    return n
  else:
    return str(uuid.uuid4()).upper()
```

In the above code, n is the field I want to update which may or may not contain a valid UUID.  The expression to run the code is:

```
CalcGUID( !GIS_ID! )
```

Where GIS_ID is the field to update.